# Drop down menu on Spinner with Background of Photo click in android

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to make app in which When user clicks on **Spinner with Background of Photo** then Drop Down menu will be opened.

But i got something weird like :

[image]

and i want to implement like this :

[image]

my code is :

```
 <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/addPhoto"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_weight="2.2"
            android:background="@drawable/addphoto" />
```

and in MainActivity :

```
 private void setPhotoSpinner() {

    ArrayAdapter<String> photoAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
            MainActivity.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
            new String[] { "Take Photo", "Choose From Gallery" });

               photoAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    addPhoto = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.addPhoto);
    addPhoto.setAdapter(photoAdapter);
}
```

Comment: please explain in detail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

u can use a `Button` instead of `Spinner` on clicking on that button open a [**PopupWindow**](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/PopupWindow.html). Set that button as `anchor` of that `PopupWindow`.Take a look at this [**Tutorial**](http://www.codeofaninja.com/2013/04/show-listview-as-drop-down-android.html)

In `PopupWindow` u can use `ListView with static data(Take Photo and Choose from Gallery)`

Answer (score 1):

You need a **[Popup menu](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/PopupMenu.html)**  on a button. You can add one button with desirable View & open Popup menu on clicking of it.

Spinner view will look like the selected view in spinner('Take Photo' in your case).

Answer (score 0):

please do like this

```
button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            spinner.performClick();
        }
    });
```

Thanx.